# Is caching a good idea in this scenario and if so what kind

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using asp.net with sql server 2008 r2

I am building a website where users can run reports based off information in a database.  For one of the reports I have about 6 checkboxlists that dynamically load based off the information in the database which then users can select certain boxes to narrow down the information that will be included in their report.

The data that populates these checkboxlists does not update but about once every couple days. Right now I have the check boxes loading in the initialize control event for each checkboxlist.  Each time I select a different tab and then come back to the tab which includes these checkboxlists it seems to reload the checkboxlists each time which is slow and takes about 6-10 seconds.

I am new to caching, is this where it would be helpful to cache the data that loads into the checkboxlists so the site will not need to perform continuous loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes caching would be helpful in this case.

You can read more about caching application data here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.100).aspx

You could cache at your data access layer, then your logic would be:

- Get checkbox data

  - Check if data is stored in cache

    - if so, return it
    - if not, hit the database for it, store it the result in cache, then return it.

For specific information about how to add to and read from the cache, see the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes
If you're checkboxes load data through Ajax, then you should probably use ASP.NET output caching capabilities.

If you render them on the server - you could store the data in some DataObject (singleton, or static field of some object) so it would be available to all requests that you server serves.

You could wrap this functionality in a singleton object, that when initialized load the data from the DB, and then on each get of the data check whether it should be reloaded (and reloads it if needed)